# How to focus second field when click on next button In React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am trying to implement a functionality when user click on next button after that I want to focus on next field . It possible through `ref` but I don't want to use it , I want to implement this functionality without ref . could someone please help me how to achieve me goal . Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify why you don't want to use `ref` for this? I guess it's because you're looking for a "more React-y" way of doing this but I'm not sure it exists.

Answer (score 0):

.focus is a function on the native element. You won't be able to accomplish this in react without using refs.